# Formatting stuff with date() function to show an advance date

Tags: php, date, time

I used below code:

```
echo "Today, " . date("M ") . date('d');
```

OUTPUT:

```
Today, Jan 05
```

When I need an advance date like tomorrow, I used below code:

```
echo date('l, ', time()+3600*24), date("M "), date('d')+1;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sunday, Jan 6
```

This time I got a problem, it shows `Jan 6` but I need `Jan 06`. A Zero is missing before 6. How could I modify my code to solve this stuff?

Comment: Please read about the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function in PHP manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date("l, M d",strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding 1 to 05 and it's automatically converted to integer.

Use the code below instead:

```
echo date('l, M d', time()+3600*24);
```

for tomorrow date